# stdin seems much slower than stdout (python). Why?

Tags: python, io, stdio

I have two python programs (one is a subprocess) that need to communicate with each other.  Currently I am doing that through `stdin` and `stdout`.  However, writing to the subprocess's `stdin` seems painfully slow.

`a.py`, a program that takes an arbitrary line of input and prints the time:

```
from time import time, sleep
from sys import stdout, stdin
while True:
    stdin.readline()
    stdout.write('%f\n' % time())
    stdout.flush()
```

`b.py`, a program that runs `a.py` and times how long it took to write to the program's `stdin` and read from it's `stdout`:

```
from time import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading import Thread
stdin_times = []
stdout_times = []
p = Popen(['python', 'a.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
for i in range(100000):
    t1 = time()
    p.stdin.write(b'\n')
    p.stdin.flush()
    t2 = float(p.stdout.readline().strip().decode())
    t3 = time()
    stdin_times.append(t2 - t1)
    stdout_times.append(t3 - t2)
p.kill()
print('stdin (min/ave):', min(stdin_times), sum(stdin_times) / len(stdin_times))
print('stdout (min/ave):', min(stdout_times), sum(stdout_times) / len(stdout_times))
```

Sample output:

```
stdin (min/ave): 1.69277191162e-05 0.000138891274929
stdout (min/ave): 1.78813934326e-05 2.09228754044e-05
```

I'm using Python 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Why is writing to `a.py`'s `stdin` so much slower than reading from its `stdout`?
Is there anyway I can get these two programs to communicate faster?

Comment: How many times have you run this test to come up with those numbers? Perhaps between the time `a.py` and `b.py` were scheduled, `crond` may have started an `updatedb` task or `ntpdate` might have skewed your clock or...

Comment: Updated to show averages

Comment: You don't want averages in this context, you want minimum times (since "best case" = "nothing else interfering").

Comment: You also want to get all the extraneous junk out of your timing loop. Cache the method lookups, use b'\n' instead of calling encode, calculate t2 *after* recording t3. However, you're still going to be at the mercy of the OS scheduler. If it has decided the worker process is non-interactive, it may be optimising its scheduling for IO throughput rather than low latency.

Comment: I've updated to show mins and they are comparable, but I don't think that really helps me.  I'm not trying to prove the theoretical inferiority of stdin; I just need my process to be able to communicate faster (on average).

Comment: I get the opposite result on my Windows box:  ``stdin (min/ave): 0.0 2.5559999942779542e-05
  stdout (min/ave): 0.0 1.6610000133514404e-05``

Comment: @ncoghlan, Is there a way I can make myself slightly less at the mercy of the OS scheduler?  Could I give it some hints to schedule for low latency rather than high throughput?

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but you may want to ask that as a separate question (if searching doesn't provide nay helpful hints). Something like increasing the priority of the child process may be another alternative.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a time precision issue ? Usually time functions are accurate about 1ms (even thought the value return lots of digit), so trying to time stuff shorter than 1 ms doesn't give consistent data.

Comment: No, I'm not really certain about anything at this point.  It may be worth noting that in the original program that spawned this question, there are 6 subprocesses, not just one.  So this example may not even be what I want.  Maybe want I want to investigate is the scalability of stdin vs stdout.

Answer (score 2):

I'd see if you can reproduce this when disabling buffering on both input and output. I have a hunch that output is being (line) buffered by default (as it is in most languages: perl, .NET, C++ iostreams)

Comment: python subprocess defaults bufsize to 0 <http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/subprocess.html>.  Also, I'm obviously flushing every time the output needs to be flushed.  Isn't flushing when I need to just as good as setting the buffer sizes to 0?

Comment: it's just as good, but it's not the same. depending on what was costing time, it may make the difference...

Answer (score 0):

If I try this a few times, the variance of the numbers is very high.

Maybe you should set up a more sane test to benchmark stdin and stdout, without a lot of other overhead, so you don't measure other stuff that's going on on your cpu. Also you're measuring string operations and float conversion.

Comment: That's not the opposite.  stdin is still slower in your example.  Also, I've updated my post to show averages

Comment: That's not actually reversed, it's just that both are being printed in the same output format -- the `stdin` time is still greater than the `stdout` time.